# Update mysql table if row excist if not add new

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

First here I have js/jquery/ajax code:

```
$('#sacuvajMapu').click(function (e) {
 $.ajax({
            url: "insertMap.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { ajdi:ajdi, mapData:$('#mapData').val();}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            } 
            error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            }
        });
        });


        });
```

also I have mysql database: [image]

Now I need to insert data with my ajax code to database so I write:

```
      try {        
            $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO map (id_parcele, json, user_id)
VALUES (:1,:2,:3);");

            $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['ajdi']);
            $STH->bindParam(':2', $_POST['mapData']);
            $STH->bindParam(':3', $user_id);
```

and all is OK.

Now I have a problem.
I must check if value `$_POST['ajdi']` is in table column `id_parcele` and if it is then just to update table column `json` with values from `$_POST['mapData']` and if `POST['ajdi']` does not exist in table column `id_parcele` then I need to add new row with data above...

How I can do this?
What is the right way for that?

Comment: You can use `rowCount()` to check if a row exists. That's one option.

Comment: in mysql you can specify a `insert ... on duplicate key update` syntax that will update a row if the key already exists. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the record already existing will throw a primary key violation, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO map (id_parcele, json, user_id)
VALUES (:1,:2,:3)
on duplicate key update json=values(json), user_id=values(user_id)
```

This syntax is MySQL specific. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I write this:  try {        
                $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO map (id_parcele, json, user_id)
VALUES (:1,:2,:3)
on duplicate key update json=values(json), user_id=values(user_id)");

                $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['ajdi']);
    $STH->bindParam(':2', $_POST['mapData']);
    $STH->bindParam(':3', $user_id);
 but again add same data as new rows...

Comment: is id_parcele setup as primary key?

Comment: no as you can see from photo above my primary is ID, id_parcele must be unique ?

Comment: Yes. If you aren't including a uniqueid in the columnlist this method doesn't work.

Comment: when I try to make it primary I get: 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: @gmaestro: In order for the `INSERT` operation to throw a "duplicate key" exception, it has to actually violate a UNIQUE (or PRIMARY) KEY constraint. If there's no UNIQUE constraint on id_parcele, the INSERT operation will succeed. You can add a UNIQUE constraint on the column `id_parcele`, as long as there are no duplicate values already in the table.

Comment: Do something like `alter tablename change id_parcele id_parcele int unique;`

Comment: now is fine becouse I delete id_parcele and add again with primary ... THANKS VERY MUCH

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a single query (as long as you put a unique key on `id_parcele`) with the following:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
INSERT INTO map (id_parcele, json, user_id)
VALUES (:1,:2,:3)
on duplicate key update json=// etc etc
```

You can also use the [Replace Into](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) syntax if you simply want to replace the values each and every time:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See Section 13.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”.

```
replace INTO map (id_parcele, json, user_id)
VALUES (:1,:2,:3)
```

Again however, you will need to have a primary key or unique index on `id_parcele`.

The difference is that the `replace into` syntax will simply delete the old row first, then insert whatever you have in your query values - while the `on duplicate...` syntax allows you do do something like adding a counter to see how many updates have happened to that row by using the values in it already:

Assuming your original row was created with 0 in a field called `parcel_updates` (and there was such a column) you could do the following:

```
INSERT INTO map (id_parcele, json, user_id, parcel_updates)
VALUES (:1,:2,:3,0)
on duplicate key update parcel_updates=parcel_updates+1
```

This would keep the original values intact, but increase the count by one in the `parcel_updates` field.

Edit: Indexes

To [add an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) to a table that already exists, you need to run something like this (only once) before these types of commands will work:

```
CREATE unique INDEX parcelID ON map (id_parcele);
```

This will then not allow more than one row with the same value for `id_parcele`. You should however make sure that you don't already have the same value in there more than once. You can also [define a column as unique](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) when creating the table (for future reference):

```
create table map(
id_parcele int(10) unique key,
// etc etc
```

Comment: +1, good points about the `REPLACE`. I'd also add a comment that the DELETE operation (if it happens), will cause any delete trigger on the table to be fired, and (if InnoDB engine) the `ON DELETE` rules of any referencing foreign key will be invoked (CASCADE, SET NULL, RESTRICT). (You specified that the DELETE operation would be performed; I just want to highlight that it is a *real* delete. May not be a concern for OP, but in the more general case, something we need to be aware of.

Comment: I write:  try {        
                $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO map (id_parcele, json, user_id)
VALUES (:1,:2,:3)
on duplicate key update json=values(json), user_id=values(user_id)");

                $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['ajdi']);
    $STH->bindParam(':2', $_POST['mapData']);
    $STH->bindParam(':3', $user_id);
but again add same data as new row...

Comment: @gmaestro I made an edit explaining how to create a unique index on the table so that these SQL queries will work for you.

Comment: THANKS, but I do it in phpmyAdmin, Thanks very much for help